# How to handle WCF connection when calling method in loop

Tags: wcf-client, connection

I am calling WCF method in for loop. I have couple of questions in this regard,

1) In this case if error occurs while its in the loop, where to re-open the connection?

2) Where to close the connection?

```
MyProxy.DemoServiceClient wsDemo = new MyProxy.DemoServiceClient();

foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTABLE.Rows)
{
    Product product = new Product();

    //Populate product using DataRow.

    try
    {
        wsDemo.CreateProduct(product);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Abort and re-open the connection in the catch
2. You can close the connection outside the loop. However if you anticipate being in the loop for long, then I would prefer using a counter and closing the connection everytime the counter gets to, say 50. And use a finally block to close the connection if its not already aborted or closed.